# Does Thymoquinone give cedar its distinctive smell?

Tags: botany, food-chemistry, olfaction, plant-perception

What chemical gives cedar wood its distinctive smell? Is it the same that gives *Nigella sativa* its cedar-like smell?

- Schreiner, Linda et al., “[What Does Wood Smell like? Characterization of Odorants in Wood](https://openlib.tugraz.at/download.php?id=5b6957d92f6e2&location=browse),” accessed January 7, 2022, DOI: [10.3217/978-3-85125-593-5-82](https://doi.org/10.3217/978-3-85125-593-5-82).

mentions Thymoquinone, "known to be the major compound in black cumin seed (*Nigella sativa*)", which is also in incense cedar, but is Thymoquinone the primary chemical giving cedar its distinctive smell?

Comment: @tyersome I've added my research, focused the question to be about Thymoquinone.

Comment: Unfortunately, no time to write up an answer or research further. But see [Odor-active constituents of Cedrus atlantica wood essential oil](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/28968531/) which attributes THE ODOUR of cedar wood to vestitenone and 4-acetyl-1-methylcyclohexene but also contains the sentence "The _composition_ of Cedrus atlantica essential oil is generally dominated by alpha- and beta-himachalenes" (emphasis mine) which seems to agree with what is written [here](http://www.users.globalnet.co.uk/~nodice/new/magazine/cedar/cedar.htm).  To my mind, the Phyochemistry article looks good